# Given examples of complete non-Archimedean field of characteristic $p$ s.t. $K$ is not $F$-finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, rigid-analytic-spaces

Let $K$ be a complete non-Archimedean field of characteristic $p$ with valuation ring $A$. We say a ring $R$ is $F$-finite if it is of characteristic $p$ and the absolute Frobenius map $F_R$ is finite.

We know if $A$ is $F$-finite then $K$ is $F$-finite as a localization of $F$-finite map. So the case $A$ is $F$-finite and $K$ is not $F$-finite is not possible. But I can't deduce about other situations. So I would like to know examples for the other three cases:

1. $A$ is not $F$-finite, $K$ is $F$-finite.
2. $A$ is not $F$-finite, $K$ is not $F$-finite.
3. $A$ is $F$-finite, $K$ is $F$-finite.

The case 3 is probably the most simple one, $K=\mathbb{F}_p((t)),A=\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ should do the job. For case 1 and 2, $A$ is better to be non-Noetherian because $F$-finite ring is excellent (by Kunz) so Noetherian. Thanks in advance!

Comment: anything unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to know if $K/K^p$ is a finite extension and if $A$ is a finitely generated $A^p$-module.

- With $A= \Bbb{F}_p[[t]]$ both are.
- With $A= \Bbb{F}_p(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)[[t]]$ neither are.
- Let $K$ be the completion of $\Bbb{F}_p[x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}]$ for the valuation $v(x^ny^m) = n+\sqrt2 m$ ie. $$K = \{ \sum_{j\ge 1} c_j t^{b_j},c_j\in \Bbb{F}_p, b_j\in \Bbb{Z+\sqrt2\ Z}, \lim_{j\to \infty} b_j=\infty\}$$ $v(\sum_{j\ge 1} c_j t^{b_j})=\inf \{ b_j,c_j\ne 0\}$.

  Then $[K:K^p]=p^2$, while $A$ is not a finitely generated $A^p$-module:

  If $A=A^p+\sum_{m=1}^M a_m A^p$ then wlog $v(a_m)>0$ so that for $v(\alpha)<\inf v(a_m))$ we'd have $v(\alpha)\in \Bbb{pZ+\sqrt2\ p Z}$, contradicting that the elements in $(\Bbb{Z+\sqrt2\ Z})_{\ge 0}, \not \in (\Bbb{pZ+\sqrt2\ p Z})_{\ge 0}$ can be arbitrary small.

Comment: Can you explain why $K=\mathbb{F}_p (x_1,x_2,x_3,...)((t))$ is not $F$-finite?

Comment: The residue field of $K^p=\Bbb{F}_p(x_1^p,x_2^p,\ldots)((t^p))$ and $\Bbb{F}_p(x_1,x_2,\ldots)/\Bbb{F}_p(x_1^p,x_2^p,\ldots)$ is not a finite extension.

Comment: Do you suggest that $F$-finiteness of $K$ implies $F$-finiteness of its residue field? I can see $F$-finiteness of $A$ implies $F$-finiteness of its residue field, but not this. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I found a reference that for a excellent Noetherian domain $A$ of charistic $p$, $A$ is $F$-finite if and only if the fraction field $K$ is $F$-finite. And a reference that for a Noetherian complete ring $A$ of characterisitc $p$, $A$ is of $F$-finite if and only if the residue field $\kappa$ is $F$-finite. So in the case of $A=L[[t]]$, we have $K$ is $F$-finite iff $A$ is $F$-finite iff $L$ is $F$-finite.

Comment: @ZWu It is clear that $[\Bbb{F}_p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)((t)):\Bbb{F}_p(x_1^p,\ldots,x_n^p)((t^p))] = p^{n+1}$

Comment: True. But I don't see an easy deduction of $[\mathbb{F_p}(x_1,...)((t)):\mathbb{F_p}(x_1^p,...)((t^p))]\geq [\mathbb{F_p}(x_1,...,x_n)((t)):\mathbb{F_p}(x_1^p,...,x_n^p)((t^p))]$.

Comment: You should. $ {}{}{}$

Comment: I do feel like there should be an easy deduction but I tried and failed to deduce that, I am sorry if it looks stupid, can you enlighten me?

Comment: If $K/F$ is a finite extension then for every $K/E/F$ we have $[E:F]\le [K:F]$ (the dimensions of $E,K$ as $F$ vector spaces). Here for all $n$ there is $E$ such that $[E:F]\ge p^{n+1}$

Comment: This argument reduces to show $[\mathbb{F}_p(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1}^p,x_{n+2}^p,...):\mathbb{F}_p(x_1^p,...)]= [\mathbb{F}_p(x_1,...,x_n):\mathbb{F}_p(x_1^p,...,x_n^p)]=p^{n+1}$, which can be proved by checking they have the same set of generators. Thanks!